# Ajax doesn't respond

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying again - I'm trying to create simple code: when I change the value in the `select` dropdown, Ajax will run and print "HELLO AJAX" in the second `div` tag

But I don't get any response.

What am I doing wrong?

**index.php**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#first").click( 
    function(){

    //  var area_id=$("#first").val(); 

        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "recs.php",
    //  data: "area_id="+area_id,
        dataType:'text',
        cache:false,
        success: 
          function(data){
            $("#second").html(data); 

          }

        });

      return false;

    });


});


</script>




<form method="post" action="#">

    <select id="first" name="area_id">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

<div id="second"></div>

</form>
```

**recs.php**

```
HELLO AJAX
```

Comment: You're not being very clear. 1) You are displaying `.php` files but saying that you're not using PHP. Interesting...if this is the case, you might as well switch all your files to `.html`. 2) Have you used any debugging tools like the Browser's console or Fiddler to see the network traffic. You can't legitimately say you're not getting anything back. You may very well be getting an error response such as a ***400*** or ***502***. You don't have your error callback setup though so you will never know. You need to do some more debugging and provide us with more information before we can help...

Comment: See my answer, you probably miss jquery inclussion. However, War1ock was right. If you are using firefox, you can use network tab of firebug (install firebug first). If you are using google chrome, use chrome developer tools. This will help you to know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you miss to include jquery.

Try to add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

at the beginning of index.php

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhh, so stupied!
Thanks! know working...:)

Answer (score 0):

change the jQuery to

```
$("#first").change(function() {
       //ajax
    });
```

and echo the text from recs.php file:

```
<?php echo 'HELLO AJAX'; ?>
```

Comment: If the only content in the file is either `<?php echo 'HELLO AJAX'; ?>`  or `HELLO AJAX` there should be no difference.

Comment: @t.niese Not following. Why is there no difference?

Comment: I'm not using PHP code in recs.php file @t.niese

Comment: $("#first").click () is this correct way to handle a change in select box..??

Comment: first, make sure you entering into the Jquery function then follow the answer

Comment: @War10ck imprecise: everything outside the `<?php ?>` blocks is sended as if you would echo it. e.g. `<?php if($something) {?>test<?php } ?>` is equal to `<?php if( $something) { echo "test"; }?>`

Comment: @t.niese Good point. Never thought of that. Thanks :)

Comment: I tried with and without text inside <?PHP ?> tags - still not working.
I think I do something wrong with the script/ajax code

Comment: do you correct the JQuery onchange funtion

Comment: @Roi Why don't you add the error callback and find out. You won't even know if you have an error response without it unless you check the console.

Comment: @War10ck - you won't believe what was the problem...now its fix...